# Unable to populate list from databae

Tags: php, sql, database

I am trying to retreive data from a database and populate a list from it, there doesnt seem to be errors in my code and still the list is not populating, my code

```
<?php 
 $hostname = "localhost";
 $username = "username";
 $password = "password";
 $dbase = "db";
 $link = @ mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
 $db_selected = @ mysql_select_db($dbase);
 ?>


<?php 
    include("scripts/dbconnect.php"); 
    $query="select class from school";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $numrows=mysql_num_rows($result);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
     echo '<option value="'.$row['class'].'">'.$row['class'].'</option>';
    }  
   ?>
```

any help much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options must be wrapped with select tag:

```
 echo "<select name='class'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
 echo '<option value="'.$row['class'].'">'.$row['class'].'</option>';
}  
 echo "</select>";
```

Additionally do:

```
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    break;
}
```

To see if there are any errors of mysql connection.

Comment: it still doesnt seem to work, is there a way to check if the database connection is successful?

Comment: i think the problem is with this html code -                          <select name="menu" id="main"> any ideas maybe?

Comment: Right click on your page, select view source code, what do you see?

Comment: Could not connect: Access denied for user 'timetable'@'localhost' (using password: NO)   so yeah db error???

Comment: Fix this one first _include("scripts/dbconnect.php");_ either path or content of it are messed up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to echo a `select` element.

```
<?php 
    include("scripts/dbconnect.php"); 
    $query="select class from school";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $numrows=mysql_num_rows($result);
    echo "<select>"
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
     echo '<option value="'.$row['class'].'">'.$row['class'].'</option>';
    }  
    echo "</select>"
   ?>
```